# fadeIn() callback function not waiting until fadeIn() is complete

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm trying to create a function that will fade in appends to an element. To ensure the animations run sequentially and wait for the previous animation to finish, I'm trying to use a callback function (recursively) with fadeIn.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var messages = [];
    messages.push("First message");
    messages.push("Second message")

    function appendContentText(newText, callbackFunction, callbackArgument) {
        $("<div>" + newText + "</div>").hide().appendTo("#content").fadeIn(1000, callbackFunction(callbackArgument));
    }

    function runMessageSequence(introCounter = 0) {
        if (introCounter == messages.length) return;
        else appendContentText(messages[introCounter], runMessageSequence, introCounter + 1);
    }

    runMessageSequence();
});
```

The messages all fade in together though. So it seems to me like the subsequent fadeIn's are being called immediately rather than after the 1000 ms delay.

I suspect this might have something to do with the order I'm applying things like 'hide' and 'appendTo' and 'fadeIn' to the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are probably calling the function right away instead of referencing it. If you just edit as follows, it does what you want

```
$("<div>" + newText + "</div>").hide().appendTo("#content").fadeIn(1000, function(){
    callbackFunction(callbackArgument)
});
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8d0qsh5/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's because my callback containing an argument causes it to be called immediately. Thank you very much. My jvs is a bit rusty.

Comment: Yes. If you put just `fadeIn(1000, callbackFunction );` it does its job, by adding the brackets, you call it right away